# Django - Media upload [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm having some trouble getting django to play nice with image uploads. My script will create directories based on the date like so:

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%m-%Y/')
```

Now, if I create the dated directory in the uploads folder and chmod the folder to 755, the upload works fine, but if I try to chmod the uploads folder without creating the dated sub folder (which I need django to do), I am getting a permissions error.

How do I make it so a folder will allow the creation of sub folders?

Here is a traceback:

```
Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'tagging',
 'mediamanager',
 'livesettings',
 'projects']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/enigma-dev/enigma/mediamanager/views.py" in upload_media
  24.           m.upload_media(data=form.cleaned_data, params=params)
File "/var/www/enigma-dev/enigma/mediamanager/models.py" in upload_media
  63.       self.save()
File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  460.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  543.                         for f in meta.local_fields if not isinstance(f, AutoField)]
File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
  255.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  92.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
  49.         name = self._save(name, content)
File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/core/files/storage.py" in _save
  166.             os.makedirs(directory)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/os.py" in makedirs
  171.     mkdir(name, mode)

Exception Type: OSError at /media-manager/upload/
Exception Value: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/site-dev/site/static/uploads/04-2011'
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The process that is running your Python interpreter doesn't have permission to write into the media directory. You'll need to either `chgrp` or `chown` the media directory to the same group as your Python process, and ensure you have at least `g+rwx` on directories and `g+rw` on files.

Comment: Sorry, could you tell me what command I would use to find out the permissions on a folder? I am using ubuntu.

Comment: And how can you tell which group the Python process is on? Thanks!

Comment: If you are running nginx, usually it's www-data. So `chown www-data:www-data -R media`command would work.

It seems you are missing -R(recursive) option when giving permission.

Comment: @chhantyal Thank you guy, you save my whole day ;)

Answer (score 27):

I was getting the same error and fix it by changing:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
```

to:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
```

Under `settings.py`.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have done following

Your settings.py

```
...
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
...
```

Also set permission to media directory

```
chgrp -R www-data /path/to/media/
chmod -R g+w  /path/to/media/
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I forgot to add: MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media') to my settings.py file on my production server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/10949995/clement-tong for the inspiration. I experienced the same error in a production environment and I had to change settings.py file to include a preceding forward slash:

`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/media")`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and fix it by doing the following in setting.py file of the project:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
```

**to**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
```