# Permission Denied to Upload Django

Tags: django

i'm try upload file with django(xlsx) this is my code:

```
myfile = request.FILES['document']
fs = FileSystemStorage()
filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
```

on the model i have setup the folder "media" to uploads, get this error:

```
Permission denied: '/var/www/html/inventariosRG/media/my_file.xlsx'
```

this error i'm try fixed with this:

```
  PATH = 'media/'
  myfile = request.FILES['document']
  try:
     import subprocess
     RUTA_ABSOLUTA = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),PATH)
     subprocess.Popen('sudo chmod -R 777 '+RUTA_ABSOLUTA, shell=True)
  except Exception as e:
     raise Exception ("Error ",e)
 fs = FileSystemStorage()
 filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
```

this code only show the same error "permission denied..." please i'm try set the permission by command on django, any suggest thanks..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These answers probably relate and are better than 777-ing:
[Django - Media upload [Errno 13] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543641/django-media-upload-errno-13-permission-denied?rq=1)

A file from the internet is owned by user 'www-data:www-data' and that user has tightly restricted permissions (because files from the internet might be bad.) Your Django `media/` folder needs to be accessible and writeable to the www-data user, so making that owner the user is appropriate.

Also, I'm not a sysadmin by any means and I may be speaking from unrecognized ignorance, but building the use of `sudo` into your Django application seems like a big security risk to me.

I can see a use for a 'config' script, that ensures a new deployment rolls out correctly, but keep that script and your Django code well separated from files from the internet. You could add your script to `/etc/sudoers` to give it the authority it needs (but remember to edit `sudoers` with `visudo`) if there was some reason to automate it.